# How to configure my Android app with gradle 4.6 version

Tags: android, gradle, apk, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use gradle to build android app because I don't have enough memory for android studio.

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/
```

I followed this link guide but this for version 2.3
and the version that I download it is 4.6
so when I try to add the android plugin it doesn't work.
and I get the following error message:

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/mz/programming/hello-app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello-app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

till now I didn't found a good guide or documentation for the version 4.6

Answer (score 1):

To use gradle 4.4+, android gradle plugin 3.1.0+ is required, check whether you are using the correct version or not. [Checkout this link for for more information on supported gradle versions by android plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle)